# setColorFilter not working with resource color

Tags: android

If I use setColorFilter like this, it works and paint my image with the chosen color:

```
int color = Color.parseColor("#FF0000"); 
viewHolder.Icon.setColorFilter(color);
```

But if I try to use a resource color, it does nothing:

```
viewHolder.Icon.setColorFilter(R.color.colorPrimary);
```

where the resource is defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#FF5722</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answer marked as "right" use getColor() method which is deprecated.
That's why here is up-to-date answer:

```
int color = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.my_color, null);
```

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
int actionBarBackground = getResources().getColor(R.color.actionBarBackground);
```

and you set actionBarBackground in the method setColorFilter thats all

Answer (score 1):

please add   PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY  See below example

viewHolder.Icon.getDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );